# Azure Function to only run when token response has expired

Tags: azure-functions

I have an azure function that simply runs an API call to fetch an AD Access Token.  My tokens are set to have a life of 1 hour.

Currently each time I call the Function (via http) it makes a new API call to get a new Access Token.  Ideally I would like the function to only make a new API call if the previous Access Token has expired or is close to expiring (within 10 mins).

Here is my function script:

```
const axios = require('axios').default;

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('FetchToken HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    const tenant_id = GetConfig('tenant_id');
    const client_id = GetConfig('client_id');
    const client_secret = GetConfig('client_secret');
    const resource = GetConfig('resource');
    const url = GetConfig('url').replace("#tenant_id#", tenant_id);

    var data = `grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=${client_id}&client_secret=${client_secret}&resource=${resource}`

    var config = {
        method: 'post',
        url,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        },
        data
    };
    try {
        var res = await axios(url, config);
        if (res.status == 200) {
            const expires_on_date_time = new Date(res.data.expires_on * 1000).toLocaleString();
            const issue_on_date_time = new Date(res.data.not_before * 1000).toLocaleString();
            context.res = {
                status: 200,
                body: {
                    expires_on_date_time,
                    issue_on_date_time,
                    ...res.data
                }
            };
        }
    } catch (error) {

        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: error
        };
    }
}

function GetConfig(configName) {
    return process.env[ configName ]
}
```

...and here is a sample response:

```
{
  "expires_on_date_time": "3/8/2022, 6:22:17 PM",
  "issue_on_date_time": "3/8/2022, 5:17:17 PM",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "expires_in": "3599",
  "ext_expires_in": "3599",
  "expires_on": "1646763737",
  "not_before": "1646759837",
  "resource": "https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api",
  "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImpTMVhvMU9XRGpfNTJ2YndHTmd2UU8yVnpNYyIsImtpZCI6ImpTMVhvMU9XRGpfNTJ2YndHTmd2UU8yVnpNYyJ9.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.OnpziHqFn3Ql2cGpJevzS9mcE69rbZFD2KLCvGsWD3DpHOZ6ZCb8WbQaPHelQ74uYRVbIHBmvwRPR2PI4VIYKVp6ouIiwFYxFmwvDEF0klvekfPQwpUcdyQ-hgKP_gnqXQrTWHsLOlOMerfd3XMGknvZ90E9bAZnZkQX4nYpiFHJiewy93Fjv6P3n8W3flkZ64Vrte_qeeEeLN3cnPA0DZJTc-4dHI5fY2HJxAnVXQzSUSwNQlLysMjTIy0tbn458kU65Q7O3-EZfRKtYRoTgmuilwQqCqqrylJt4dVNWbRSNgGZszWauanFOu7b7ESXukobeaE06nl1FGb0s_Ackw"
}
```

I would like the Function to first check the expiry of the previous call's token and if it's within 10 mins of expiring then fetch a new token.

Any pointers?

Comment: Why not make your function a timer triggered one, that runs every 50mins [ say 50th min of every hour expressed as CRON expression].

Comment: I like that idea although there will be large periods in time where the function isn't needed and I don't really want it running if it's not needed.

Comment: You are using the token in some other application module, why not that make a call to your HTTP trigger function when it is near to token expiry? This way, you can leave your function app stateless, which is the ideal.

Comment: I did think about that however if there are multiple users using the application I guess each user would have their own variant of a timer and HTTP trigger running in the script?

Comment: The application backend (server side) can keep the list of user tokens, and one timer function/thread that iterates and just calls the az function app http trigger(stateless) passing the user for which token to be refreshed.